# Extract SOAP object from HttpServletRequest

Tags: servlets, soap, cxf

How do you extract the SOAP object from a HttpServletRequest.

In my filter AuthenticationEntryPoint i have the methode

```
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException
```

and i want to extract SOAP request from HttpServletRequest ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream inStream = request.getInputStream();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), inStream);
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter(); 
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    soapMessage.writeTo(out); 
    String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray()); 
    writer.println(strMsg);
```